# Задание целых чисел

Tags: python

В каком python появилась возможность задания целых чисел как:

```
1_000_000
```

Где это описано в документации?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В 3.6 появилось. Описано в [PEP-515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/).